# Angular CLI route

Tags: routes, angular-cli

When executing command:

```
ng generate route someName
```

I am getting error like this:

> Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system
>   events. Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
>   Due to changes in the router, route generation has been temporarily
>   disabled. You can find more information about the new router here:
>   http://victorsavkin.com/post/145672529346/angular-router

Provided links are not helpful

Comment: what angular2 version you are using , and also can you show me the output of `ng version`

Comment: angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.9; node: 5.2.0; os: darwin x64

Comment: Bonus from the [style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-02-12): *Do end the filename of a RoutingModule with `-routing.module.ts`*

Answer (score 33, accepted):

use :

```
ng g m route --routing
```

- g-> generate
- m-> module
- route-> Your route Module Name(You can use any name).

Answer (score 32):

```
ng generate module app-routing --flat --module=app
```

**--flat** puts the file in src/app instead of its own folder.

**--module=app** tells the CLI to register it in the imports array of the AppModule

[Check the details here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)

Answer (score 5):

Just like the error says, route generation is temporarily disabled in angular-cli. The reason being older router getting deprecated. Angular2 rc4 uses the new router and any new project based on angular 2 should ideally use the new router. So till angular cli updates to support new router directives, we have to manually create the router files & import required dependencies.

This is what worked for me.

- Use angular-cli to create the seed project
- Generate new components using ng g component
- Then manually add router to these components using this tutorial

  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this:

```
   ng generate module pages/home --route home --module=app
```

Answer (score 1):

The Angular 4 CLI method, given folder *app*:

- backup `app/app.module.ts`
- `ng g m ../app --routing`, then `y` to overwrite
- now we have `app/app.module.ts` and `app/app-routing.module.ts`
- merge your old `app/app.module.ts` with the new one with the router

(This avoids creating a separate folder for the router)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option `--routing`and update the routing file.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-routing

Cheers,

Carlos Rojas